# What are the odds that two people are friends in a network of 20 people?

Tags: probability

> If person $A$ has 10 friends and person $B$ has 5 friends, and they are in a network of 20 people, what are the odds that persons $A$ and $B$ are friends?

I first thought to divide into cases based on how many friends they share (so the number they share would range from 0 to 5). But when I attempted to do this, I didn't even know how to begin (my probability skills are abysmally weak). Any ideas on how to proceed or thoughts on other solutions?

Comment: He's limited to 10 friends. It's impossible for A to be friends with 20, especially considering there are 20 people including A and B.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Each of A and B have $19$ potential friends. Assuming friendship is mutual, you have two choices:  A and B are friends, then you choose 9 other friends for A out of 18 and 4 other friends for B out of 18, or A and B are not friends, so you choose 10 friends for A out of 18 and 5 friends for B out of 18.  Compute the number of ways to do each.

Comment: @vadim123:  I was assuming we select a random graph among the ones that have 20 vertices and the correct degrees at A and B, then ask what the chance A and B are connected.